# React native recording voice

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

How can I record a voice using react native and, when recording, have access to data at certain time intervals, say a second, and somehow work with this data, let’s say send it to the server, etc.

I try do this with lib react native recorder and other libs, but this did not produce results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.